# How to create game loop for Android Wear app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, wear-os

What I'm trying to do is make an version of the game Simon for android wear.  I don't want to use libgdx, tho I could if I have no other choice.

The way the game works is that the computer shows a button sequence to the player and then the player is to repeat the sequence back.  I've got it all working fine except for I can't seem to animate a sequence to the player.

What I have is a random number generator.  Using the number generated I want to change the color of the button background for a small time, then change it back.  And I loop this a set number of times.  I've tried SystemClock.sleep(500), but it just runs the loop before even showing the app.

The main problem is that everything has to be done inside an onLayoutInflated because of how wear has to choose between round and square faces.  And this has to be done in the onCreate method as far as I know.

Does anyone know a way of doing some sort of game loop and/or animation sequence for android wear.

P.S. I will append my code as soon as I fix it.  I've been fiddling with it a lot.

```
package com.happypantzinc.memory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageButton mOverlay, mTopLeft, mTopRight, mBotLeft, mBotRight;
    private Boolean isPlayerTurn = false;
    private Boolean isRunning = false;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int level = 10;
    private ArrayList<Integer> compSeq;
    private ArrayList<Integer> playSeq;

    private float screenW, screenH;

    //setup colors
    final int RED_UP        = Color.rgb(180, 0, 0);
    final int RED_DOWN      = Color.rgb(255, 77, 0);
    final int GREEN_UP      = Color.rgb(0, 180, 0);
    final int GREEN_DOWN    = Color.rgb(0, 255, 77);
    final int BLUE_UP       = Color.rgb(0, 0, 180);
    final int BLUE_DOWN     = Color.rgb(0, 77, 255);
    final int YELLOW_UP     = Color.rgb(180, 180, 0);
    final int YELLOW_DOWN   = Color.rgb(255, 255, 0);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        compSeq = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        playSeq = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mOverlay = (ImageButton) stub.findViewById(R.id.overlay);
                mTopLeft = (ImageButton) stub.findViewById(R.id.topLeft);
                mTopRight = (ImageButton) stub.findViewById(R.id.topRight);
                mBotLeft = (ImageButton) stub.findViewById(R.id.botLeft);
                mBotRight = (ImageButton) stub.findViewById(R.id.botRight);

                setupButtons();

                setupButtonActions(mTopLeft, GREEN_UP, GREEN_DOWN);
                setupButtonActions(mTopRight, RED_UP, RED_DOWN);
                setupButtonActions(mBotLeft, YELLOW_UP, YELLOW_DOWN);
                setupButtonActions(mBotRight, BLUE_UP, BLUE_DOWN);

                mOverlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        isRunning = true;
                        mOverlay.setClickable(false);
                        mOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        gameLoop();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        //get screen size
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();

        display.getSize(size);
        screenW = size.x;
        screenH = size.y;
    }

    private void gameLoop() {
        while(isRunning) {
            //Computer turn
            while (compSeq.size() < level) {
                int val = random.nextInt(4);

                if (!mOverlay.isShown()) {
                    //Computer shows sequence
                    switch (val) {
                        case 0:
                            mTopLeft.getBackground().setColorFilter(GREEN_DOWN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            System.out.println(val);
                            SystemClock.sleep(500);
                            mTopLeft.getBackground().setColorFilter(GREEN_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            mTopRight.getBackground().setColorFilter(RED_DOWN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            System.out.println(val);
                            SystemClock.sleep(500);
                            mTopRight.getBackground().setColorFilter(RED_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            mBotLeft.getBackground().setColorFilter(YELLOW_DOWN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            System.out.println(val);
                            SystemClock.sleep(500);
                            mBotLeft.getBackground().setColorFilter(YELLOW_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            mBotRight.getBackground().setColorFilter(BLUE_DOWN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            System.out.println(val);
                            SystemClock.sleep(500);
                            mBotRight.getBackground().setColorFilter(BLUE_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    compSeq.add(val);
                        SystemClock.sleep(300);
                }
            }
            isPlayerTurn = true;

            while (playSeq.size() < level) {
                //Check for correct input
                if (playSeq.size() > 0 && (playSeq.get(playSeq.size()-1) != compSeq.get(playSeq.size()-1))) {
                    isRunning = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            playSeq.clear();
            compSeq.clear();
            isPlayerTurn = false;
        }
    }

    private void setupButtons() {
        //set width and height of buttons
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;

        params = mOverlay.getLayoutParams();
        params.height   = (int) screenH;
        params.width    = (int) screenW;
        mOverlay.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = mTopLeft.getLayoutParams();
        params.height   = (int)(screenH/2);
        params.width    = (int)(screenW/2);
        mTopLeft.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = mTopRight.getLayoutParams();
        params.height   = (int)(screenH/2);
        params.width    = (int)(screenW/2);
        mTopRight.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = mBotLeft.getLayoutParams();
        params.height   = (int)(screenH/2);
        params.width    = (int)(screenW/2);
        mBotLeft.setLayoutParams(params);

        params = mBotRight.getLayoutParams();
        params.height   = (int)(screenH/2);
        params.width    = (int)(screenW/2);
        mBotRight.setLayoutParams(params);

        //set position of buttons
        mOverlay.setX(0);
        mOverlay.setY(0);

        mTopLeft.setX(0);
        mTopLeft.setY(0);

        mTopRight.setX(screenW / 2);
        mTopRight.setY(0);

        mBotLeft.setX(0);
        mBotLeft.setY(screenH / 2);

        mBotRight.setX(screenW / 2);
        mBotRight.setY(screenH / 2);

        //set initial background tints
        mTopLeft.getBackground().setColorFilter(GREEN_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        mTopRight.getBackground().setColorFilter(RED_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        mBotLeft.getBackground().setColorFilter(YELLOW_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        mBotRight.getBackground().setColorFilter(BLUE_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    private void setupButtonActions(final ImageButton button, final int tint_up, final int tint_down) {
        //create button listeners and tints
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (isPlayerTurn) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(tint_down, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(tint_up, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    }

                    //Enter correct sequence value
                    int val = 4;

                    if (button == mTopLeft) {
                        val = 0;
                    } else if (button == mTopRight) {
                        val = 1;
                    } else if (button == mBotLeft) {
                        val = 2;
                    } else if (button == mBotRight) {
                        val = 3;
                    }

                    playSeq.add(val);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use SystemClock.sleep() as you are blocking the UI thread. Probably this is the cause that the animation is done before showing the activity (The activity will not show until onCreate() finishes). This can also cause the famous ANR dialog.

You can use Handlers to do the work later without blocking the UI thread:

```
private Handler mHandler;
private int 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            computerTurnDown(); 
        }
    }, 500); //Delay time in ms
    ...
}

private void computerTurnDown(){
      final int val = random.nextInt(4);

            if (!mOverlay.isShown()) {
                //Computer shows sequence
                switch (val) {
                    case 0:
                        mTopLeft.getBackground().setColorFilter(GREEN_DOWN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                        System.out.println(val);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mTopRight.getBackground().setColorFilter(RED_DOWN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                        System.out.println(val);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mBotLeft.getBackground().setColorFilter(YELLOW_DOWN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                        System.out.println(val);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mBotRight.getBackground().setColorFilter(BLUE_DOWN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                        System.out.println(val);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                            computerTurnUp(val); 
                      }
                }, 500);
}

private void computerTurnUp(){
     switch (val) {
                    case 0:
                        mTopLeft.getBackground().setColorFilter(GREEN_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mTopRight.getBackground().setColorFilter(RED_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mBotLeft.getBackground().setColorFilter(YELLOW_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mBotRight.getBackground().setColorFilter(BLUE_UP, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                compSeq.add(val);
                if (compSeq.size() < level){
                       mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                                computerTurnDown(); 
                           }
                      }, 300);
                }else{
                     isPlayerTurn = true;
                }

}
```

Whenever you want to do some work delayed use [mHandler.postDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) and put the code in run() method.

To check the user should be done in the button listener because the way you have currently the "while (playSeq.size() < level)" will block the thread.

```
private void setupButtonActions(final ImageButton button, final int tint_up, final int tint_down) {
    //create button listeners and tints
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (isPlayerTurn) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(tint_down, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(tint_up, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }

                //Enter correct sequence value
                int val = 4;

                if (button == mTopLeft) {
                    val = 0;
                } else if (button == mTopRight) {
                    val = 1;
                } else if (button == mBotLeft) {
                    val = 2;
                } else if (button == mBotRight) {
                    val = 3;
                }

                playSeq.add(val);
                if(playSeq.size() < level) {
                     //Check for correct input
                     if (playSeq.size() > 0 && (playSeq.get(playSeq.size()-1) != compSeq.get(playSeq.size()-1))) {
                           isRunning = false;
                           isPlayerTurn = false;
                     }

                 }else{
                     playSeq.clear();
                     compSeq.clear();
                     isPlayerTurn = false;
                     onComputerDown();
                 }

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: So I use the handler like that outside of the onCreate and any other methods?

Comment: I edited the answer. The handler will execute onComputerDown after 500ms. After 500 onComputerUp will be called. I found another error in your code. You should check the playSeq on the button listener so it will only be checked when you press a button.